Access denied for MySqlBulkCopy in AWS RDS
I'm trying to use MySqlBulkCopy to load data from a DataTable in a C# program using the MySqlConnector package:
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString + ";AllowLoadLocalInfile=True"))
{
    this.ExecuteNonQuery("SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;");
    var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(conn);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = targetTable;                
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
}

When I run this example, I get the following error:

Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation

I granted SUPER to the user executing the code and that resolved the issue:
GRANT SUPER ON *.* TO {user}@'%';

Albeit, with this warning:

1 warning(s): 1287 The SUPER privilege identifier is deprecated

However, when I deployed to AWS RDS using an Aurora/MySQL database, I'm not able to grant the SUPER role when using serverless database (which makes sense):

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'%' (using password: YES)

Is there another lower level role/privilege that I can grant in the serverless environment to execute the bulk insert?

Hey Paul, when you run the original command without trying to grant SUPER, do you get The used command is not allowed? Great formatting but just want to focus more on the root cause here as opposed to what seems to be a byproduct problem potentially.

Without the SUPER grant in AWS (and locally) I get the aforementioned Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation error

You didn't specify which library you use but I assume it's MySqlConnector. The MySqlBulkCopy uses LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE underneath. If you can't use that command, you can't use MySqlBulkCopy no matter the permissions. You'll have to use an option that is supported by RDS, One such option is to load from an S3 bucket with LOAD DATA FROM S3

Correct.  As I mentioned in the question, I am "using the MySqlConnector package".  So if the permissions required for that are non grantable, I'll use a different method.
